# Python type showing instance before return but none after

Tags: python, object

I have a function used to build a tree from a set of nodes

```
def buildTree(self, nodeList,):
        if len(nodeList) > 1:
            nodeList = sorted(nodeList, key=self.getKey)
            newNode = self.makeNode(nodeList[0], nodeList[1])
            nodeList.pop(0)
            nodeList.pop(0)
            nodeList.append(newNode)

            nodeList = self.buildTree(nodeList)
        else:
            print type(nodeList[0])
            return nodeList[0]
```

This outputs type 'instance'

```
from TreeFactory import TreeFactory
nodeList = builder.buildNodeList(
    'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog')

nodeHead = builder.buildTree(nodeList)

print type(nodeHead)
```

When I print the type of the return from the builder, I get "type 'NoneType'" printed out

So why is it a valid instance before the return, but not after?

Comment: Note that the `if` branch is failing to return anything (and is therefore implicitly returning `None`).

Comment: Yup, that was the issue, I wasn't returning anything for the if branch and the recursion was causing the list to fill up with Nones. I can't believe I missed something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/users/367273/npe the issue was that the if branch was returning nothing, so the recursion was causing nodeList to be filled with None values. By changing the buildTree function so that it reads as

```
def buildTree(self, nodeList,):
        if len(nodeList) > 1:
            nodeList = sorted(nodeList, key=self.getKey)
            newNode = self.makeNode(nodeList[0], nodeList[1])
            nodeList.pop(0)
            nodeList.pop(0)
            nodeList.append(newNode)

            nodeList = self.buildTree(nodeList)
            return nodeList
        else:
            return nodeList[0]
```

fixed the issue.